# Sublime Bug with Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I'm trying to do a sublime regex search and replace with a backreference. Here's my data set:

```
if(requestType.endsWith("CompleteMulti")) {
if(requestType.endsWith("CompletePartial")) {
if(requestType.endsWith("Unfulfillable")) {
```

When I run the regular expression:

```
^.+"(\w+)".+$
```

with replace statement:

```
$1
```

I get the following output:

```
completemuLti
completepaRtial
unfulfillaBle
```

As you can see the case of the letters goes all screwy. **I'm using Version 2.0.2, Build 2221**

Is this a known issue? Some google searching has not turned up any data. If anyone knows a workaround for it please let me know.

Comment: In Sublime 3 (build 3065) it works as expected, without changing case. So seems like a bug.

Comment: I tested this on Ubuntu 14.10, OS X 10.8.5, and Windows 8 using ST2, and it worked on all three for me. Are you sure there wasn't anything else in the `Replace` field?

Comment: I can reproduce this on build 3065 if I select the option "preserve case" when replacing the text as it is preserving the case of the character that was there before.. not a bug!  :)

Comment: Not a bug, eh? I really cannot think of a single use case where this would ever be the desired behavior. Maybe it's not the default action though and I changed this setting somewhere along the way when I was first learning Sublime...

Comment: @IcedDante I can think of one use case where it would be useful.. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before performing your "replace all", deselect the option "preserve case" (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)

"Preserve case" will preserve the case of the character **that was in that position before**.  A quick demonstration:

```
if(requestType.endsWith("CompleteMulti")) {
if(requestType.endsWith("CompletePartial")) {
if(requestType.endsWith("Unfulfillable")) {
completemuLti
completepaRtial
unfulfillaBle

          ^ only this character is left in upper case
```

Another example.  This time we will replace "sublime" with "bananas", using case-insensitive regex and with "preserve case" selected:

Before:

```
SUblime
suBLime
sublIME
```

After:

```
BAnanas
baNAnas
banaNAS
```

In response to IcedDante's comment, I can think of a use case where it would be the desired behaviour (contrived though it may be).. imagine a letter that you are sending out to a number of universities:

> Dear University of Blahtown,
>
> I am writing to enquire about your Applied Biology 101 course, as I
>   understand you're the leading school in the field of biology.  I have
>   always had a keen interest in the field of biological reseach and so
>   this course, Applied Biology 101, is of particular interest.

and then you want to also enquire about a geography course, you could find/replace "biolog" with "geograph", maintaining the case:

> Dear University of Blahtown,
>
> I am writing to enquire about your Applied Geography 101 course, as I
>   understand you're the leading school in the field of geography.  I
>   have always had a keen interest in the field of geographical reseach
>   and so this course, Applied Geography 101, is of particular interest.

Pretty contrived, I know.

*note - I've tried looking for references to this in the documentation, but I can't find anything definite...*

Comment: @IcedDante It's not a great example, admittedly!  Maybe you hit ALT+A without realising it?

Comment: Ah, I see what you're doing here. There are times where I'm working with code where I'll have an uppercase and lowercase word I want to modify. Like a class name ShipDialog and its instance shipDialog and I want to change ship to return, for example. I think this would come in handy for that.

Comment: @IcedDante that's a much better example than my one!